# ConcurrentHashMap memory allocation

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent, concurrenthashmap

```
ConcurrentHashMap chm= new ConcurrentHashMap(8,1,16);
```

Now according to the above configuration the ConcurrentHashMap will divide the table into 16 segments. Now each segment is a individual hasmap. Let's take the entry object size as x bytes. Then what is the memory allocated to each segment. As per my understanding only 8x bytes should be allotted to the table, then how will it be divided into 16 segments. Because here the concurrency level is 16 and size of the table is 8. 8x/16 is 0.5x which is not enough to add a single entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code, freely available and coming with the JDK:

```
if (initialCapacity < concurrencyLevel)   // Use at least as many bins
    initialCapacity = concurrencyLevel;   // as estimated threads
```

So, in short, if you pass arguments that don't make sense, it fixes it for you.

Comment: thanks i was looking for the same. the code i have from google link does not contain the same so was a bit confused